# Updating data in an array pulled with importxml in google spreadsheet with another importxml

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an importxml code that fills in between the lines A3:A11 in google spreadsheet `=IMPORTXML("https://www.enucuzgb.com/";"//tbody/tr/td[6]")` this code pulls price table from one site, from other sites. But since some of the prices on this site are not up to date, I draw the prices of those sites directly from that site. But I can't write the data I took in a line between A3:A11.

To summarize, the code above pulls the price list of 9 different sites, but since the prices of 2 sites are not up to date, I want to pull 2 sites separately.

Importxml formula that pulls data from 9 sites between A3:A11 (this formula is in cell A3);

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.enucuzgb.com/";"//tbody/tr/td[6]")
```

Code in cell A9 that gets the price directly from a site;

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.bursagb.com/knight-online-gb-c-4";"/html/body/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/button[2]")
```

The error given by the formula in A3 is "The result of the array is not expanded because it will overwrite the data in range A9."

(these formulas work every minute with google apps script and get current prices)

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `To summarize, the code above pulls the price list of 9 different sites, but since the prices of 2 sites are not up to date, I want to pull 2 sites separately.` and `The error given by the formula in A3 is "The result of the array is not expanded because it will overwrite the data in range A9."`, I understood your expected result as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values 1 to 6 from `=IMPORTXML("https://www.enucuzgb.com/","//tbody/tr/td[6]")` put into cell "A3". And also, you want to retrieve the value from `=IMPORTXML("https://www.bursagb.com/knight-online-gb-c-4";"/html/body/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/button[2]")` put into cell "A9".

In this case, how about the following modification? In this modification, the xpath of `=IMPORTXML("https://www.enucuzgb.com/","//tbody/tr/td[6]")` is modified.

#### From:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.enucuzgb.com/";"//tbody/tr/td[6]")
```

#### To:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.enucuzgb.com/","//tbody/tr[position()<7]/td[6]")
```

- Please put this formula to cell "A3". By this, the values from 1 to 6 are retrieved. And, you can put your 2nd formula of `=IMPORTXML("https://www.bursagb.com/knight-online-gb-c-4";"/html/body/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/button[2]")` into cell "A9".
- For example, if you want to retrieve the values from 4 to 9, please modify xpath from `//tbody/tr[position()<7]/td[6]` to `//tbody/tr[position()>3]/td[6]`.

#### Testing:

When the above formulas are used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

Comment: I didn't know xpath had such a use, thank you for your solution and answer

Comment: Is there a formula you suggest to take the number 22.00 from the cell "Bize Sat: 22.00 TL" in the cell "A9", which is also visible in the photo you took, and multiply it by 10? In this cell, " Bize Sat: xx.xx  TL " The values ​​I indicate with x are variable, the remaining values ​​are fixed. i using this formula `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML("https://www.bursagb.com/knight-online-gb-c-4";"/html/body/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/button[2]");" Bize Sat: ";"");" TL";"");".";"")/10`

Comment: @AomineDaici Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `Is there a formula you suggest to take the number 22.00 from the cell "Bize Sat: 22.00 TL"`, how about using a formula with the xpath of `=IMPORTXML("https://www.bursagb.com/knight-online-gb-c-4","//button[@data-customer-store-product-id='414']/@data-product-buy-price")`? If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.